# Why is my image not rotating after mouse click? (javascript + css)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the image to rotate after a button click, but I cannot get the image to rotate. After putting the animation lines of css into an image:active id block in css, I was able to get the image to rotate on an active mouse click, but that is not what my assignment calls for.

HTML

```
  <a id="button" onclick="rotate()">Go</a>


  <img class="click" id="image"  src="http://placehold.it/500x500">


  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
function rotate(){
    image.className = 'click';
}
```

CSS

```
#button {
    font-family: "Verdana";
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-size: 3vmin;
    line-height: 14vmin;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    background: white;
    width: 15vmin;
    height: 15vmin;
    margin: 2vmin auto;
    border-radius: 10vmin;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
}

.click:active {
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vh;
  margin: 5vh auto 0;

  transition: height 100ms, border-width 100ms, border-color 100ms;

  animation: rotate;
  animation-delay: 100ms;
  animation-timing-function: reverse;   animation-iteration-count: normal;
  animation-duration: 1s; 
  animation-play-state: running;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
```

Comment: From where `image` comes?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak the click:active class was originally id, "#image:active"

Comment: You haven't set the degrees for the image to get rotated it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this. It seems you haven't set the **degrees**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function rotate(){
      myImg=document.getElementById('image');
      myImg.className = 'rotate';
      }
    </script>
    <style>
      .rotate {
           -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
           -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
           transform: rotate(90deg);
      }    
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a id="button" onclick="rotate()">Go</a>
    <img class="click" id="image"  src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`active` is uninitialized when you use it, assuming that's the entirety of your Javascript.  You'll want to use `document.getElementById('active')` instead.

Your function sets the class of the element to 'click', which doesn't make much sense since the class of the img tag is initially set to 'click'.  Nothing changes when your function is called.

The CSS selector should just be `.click` instead of `.click:active`, and the img tag shouldn't start with a class.

Comment: I tried this, and I cant get the image to respond. For some reason, when I rename the click class as #image:active, the image rotates on click, but when I rename it back to .click, it doesnt respond.